# How to execute a stored procedures on button click with parameter input

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I am new to asp.net. I am stuck at button click to execute a stored procedure with two inout parameter here.

- Input parameter  : `StartConsoleClosingID, EndConsoleClosingID`
- Stored procedure : `ConsoleClosingIDSearch`
- Data             : `GridView`

Markup:

```
<div>
    Start ID<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="107px"></asp:TextBox>
    End ID<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Seacrh" />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PaymentConsoleClosingID"
                 HeaderText="PaymentConsoleClosingID" 
                 SortExpression="PaymentConsoleClosingID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Employer SOCSO Sum" 
                 HeaderText="Employer SOCSO Sum" 
                 ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Employer SOCSO Sum" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Employee SOCSO Sum" 
                 HeaderText="Employee SOCSO Sum" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Employee SOCSO Sum" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Employer EPF Sum" 
                 HeaderText="Employer EPF Sum" 
                 ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Employer EPF Sum" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Employee EPF Sum" 
                 HeaderText="Employee EPF Sum" ReadOnly="True" 
                 SortExpression="Employee EPF Sum" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount Sum" HeaderText="Amount Sum"
                 ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Amount Sum" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DepartmentID" HeaderText="DepartmentID" 
                SortExpression="DepartmentID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Account Code" HeaderText="Account Code" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Account Code" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CLMSConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="ConsoleClosingIDSearch" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="StartConsoleClosingID" 
                PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" Name="EndConsoleClosingID" 
                PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
```

Comment: What's the exact problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the GridView at code behind. you need to write some code to bind datagridview in cs file.

```
SqlCommand Cmd = Connection.CreateCommand();
Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
Cmd.CommandText = "ConsoleClosingIDSearch";
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartConsoleClosingID", SqlDbType.Int).value = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndConsoleClosingID ", SqlDbType.Int).value = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text);

SqlDataAdapter Da = New SqlDataAdapter(Cmd);
DataTable dt = New DataTable();
Da.Fill(dt);

GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

or you can refer complete example from [here](http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bind-data-to-ASPNet-GridView-using-Stored-Procedure.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

here another code example using Sqlhelper.

```
string conString = "your connection string";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[2];
param[0] = new SqlParameter("@userid", userid);
param[1] = new SqlParameter("@param2", param2);

DataSet ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(con, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "usp_GetUserData", param);
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
```